# How to create custom Android radio buttons?

Tags: java, android, styles, radio-button, themes

I've got a couple radio button options in my android app, but I want them to look totally different. More something like below (quick mockup) in which you simply click the words you want and it makes them bold and underlined.

[image]

Does anybody know how I can achieve something like this? All tips are welcome!

Comment: If you got the answer for this the please share.
It would be a great help

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, to override the look of default widgets, you'll need to create a drawable folder and put all of your xml definitions in that folder.  Then reference that xml file within the RadioButton block of your layout.

Here's a good blog post on how to do all that:

http://blog.devminded.com/posts/custom-android-radiobutton

Answer (score 0):

I know it might be late, but it is not a reason to keep the solution for myself.

**1)** You need to implement the `.XML` layout for the `RadioGroup` and it's `RadioButton`s. Set the `RadioGroup` children orientation with `Horizontal` value to display the button side by side. Setting the `RadioButton` button with `@null` value to hide the default selector 
[image]

As following:

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/my_radiogroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/i_like_radiobutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="I Like"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/i_dont_like_radiobutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="I Dont Like"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

**2)** In your `Activity` class, initialize them and set their listener. The listener should keep track of the changes of the `RadioButton` changes and set the UI changes according to the state either select or unselect. As following:

```
    RadioGroup myRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.my_radiogroup);
    RadioButton likeRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.i_like_radiobutton);
    RadioButton dontLikeRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.i_dont_like_radiobutton);

    //Like button listener
    likeRadioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                //Make the text underlined
                SpannableString content = new SpannableString(getString(R.string.like_text));
                content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, content.length(), 0);
                buttonView.setText(content);
                //Make the text BOLD
                buttonView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            } else {
                //Change the color here and make the Text bold
                SpannableString content = new SpannableString(getString(R.string.like_text));
                content.setSpan(null, 0, content.length(), 0);
                buttonView.setText(content);
                buttonView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);

            }
        }
    });

    //Don't Like button listener
    dontLikeRadioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                //Change the color here and make the Text bold
                SpannableString content = new SpannableString(getString(R.string.like_text));
                content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, content.length(), 0);
                buttonView.setText(content);
                buttonView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            } else {
                //Change the color here and make the Text bold
                SpannableString content = new SpannableString(getString(R.string.like_text));
                content.setSpan(null, 0, content.length(), 0); 
             buttonView.setText(content);
             buttonView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);

            }
        }
    });
```

**3)** Now, the `RadioButton` will change it's color and it's TextStyle according to it's state automatically. You can add more customization if you want.

**4)** For performing the required action when the user select any of the Buttons, we need to override the `setOnCheckedChangeListener` method for the `RadioGroup` as following:

```
genderRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if (checkedId == R.id.i_dont_like_radiobutton) {
                //Do some actions
            } else if (checkedId == R.id.i_like_radiobutton){

            }
        }
    });
```

The final output will be very similar the the question image except the separator.

[image]

I hope it helps.